# Changing ConcurrencyMode

Tags: c#, wcf, concurrency, castle-windsor, wcffacility

I'm using Castle Windsor WCF Facility.
The [docs](http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.WCF-Facility-Registration.ashx) say:

> If you are switching from WCF activation to Windsor's WcfFacility, please make sure to remove the ServiceBehavior attribute from service type.

How can I then control the concurrency mode?

In vanilla WCF I'd do:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
```

It seems that with WCF Facility the concurrence mode is set to Single and I can't find a way to change it.

EDIT: The client calls asynchronously BeginFoo method and the call is not blocking on client side.
I put logging at the beginning and at the end of the BeginFoo method. The logs indicate that the server call enters and exits BeginFoo method only once at a time.

The following client calls get magically queued.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.

If you don't specify the attribute, then WCF Facility creates one for you and adds it to

```
ServiceHost.Description.Behaviors
```

So the solution is to add an attribute to Behaviors collection (Yes, the attribute implements IServiceBehavior, a bit counterintuitive though...) and set the relevant properties there.

I'm adding the behaviors in WcfServiceModel's extension OnCreated. As at this point the default behavior is already there, I had to remove it first.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, here's the code for what dzendras posted earlier:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    _container = new WindsorContainer();
    _container.AddFacility<WcfFacility>();
    _container.Register(Component.For<IHelloService>()
                                 .ImplementedBy<HelloService>()
                                 .AsWcfService(new DefaultServiceModel().OnCreated(OnCreated)));
}

private static void OnCreated(ServiceHost serviceHost)
{
    var serviceBehavior = (ServiceBehaviorAttribute) serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Single(_ => _ is ServiceBehaviorAttribute);
    serviceBehavior.ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple;
    serviceBehavior.InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

As I Tried Some ways , 
You can use

```
 [OperationContract(IsOneWay=true)]
```

this will not make client to wait for response and this can work as or replace multiple or reentrant concurrency model

Comment: The client doesn't wait. Client is able to issue next requests immediately. It's the service that does not allow concurrent calls.

Comment: @dzendras Friyank just said that it **will not** make the client wait

Comment: no issue's you can define concurrency mode at method level as , define  [ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode= ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)] attribute on top of the method, see if it works

Comment: @ElectricCoffee: And I said that the problem is not on the client side, but on the *server* side.

Comment: @Friyank: Have you tried to actually compile your code? ServiceBehaviorAttribute cannot be defined on methods...